# SAS: conditional end of execution of code

Tags: sas

This code will be part of process in SAS data Integration Studio.

I want to achieve something like:

```
%macro conditional_start();

%let check_condition = 0;

%if check_condition eq 0 %then %do;

    %send_email_that_condition_has_been_met(); /* this I have made */

    /*Below run some kind of built-in macro probably, to stop execution of the whole code below */


%end;

%mend;

/*More macros end code I don't want to execute*/
```

I cannot pack everything below in big "if" statement because they are built in blocks.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Show more the code that occurs after your `conditional_start` macro definition.  When does conditional_start get invoked ?.  Does the un-shown code contain macro definitions and invocations, only open code or a mixture ? Is `conditional_start` invoked from inside another macro ?

Comment: `conditional_start` macro stars as first transformation in the SAS DI job.
Afterwards is mixture of open-code and definitions and macros. 

The idea was to build a custom transformation in SAS DI - to execute always as first one and check if certain conditions of input tables are met and if no set macro variable `check_condition` to 0 and do not execute the entire job.

Comment: Alternatively, I was thinking whether I could use "Conditional Start" built in transformation as second step to check if `check_condition ne 0`  - If I understand it correctly in such case the entire job would not execute because this condition would not be met.

Comment: With out changing something after conditional start, I don't think you can prevent what comes after it and having execution go into a ready state.  You can try to stop the current execution with an `%ABORT CANCEL;` in the macro, but what that eventually does depends on how the macro is invoked by Studio.

Comment: Yes, whenever possible work within known operating environment rather than foist some conditions into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop SAS Program on Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470248/stop-sas-program-on-error)

Comment: @user667489 while %abort might be useful macro, itis not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put your code into "precode" (leave macro open) and "postcode" (rest of the macro) sections of your job's properties?
For example:

precode:

```
%macro the_whole_job();
```

postcode:

```
%mend the_whole_job;

%macro conditional_start();
    %let check_condition = 0;
    %if check_condition eq 0 %then %do;
         %send_email_that_condition_has_been_met(); /* this You have made */
         /*do some kind of built-in macro meaning failure, not executing the whole code above*/
    %end;
    %else %do;
         %the_whole_job;
    %end; 
%mend;
```